# Pattern Matching Tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get this function to return True, however currently it just spits out errors

```
('A',_) `elem` [('A','B')]

Found hole: _ :: Char
• In the expression: _
  In the first argument of ‘elem’, namely ‘('A', _)’
  In the expression: ('A', _) `elem` [('A', 'B')]
• Relevant bindings include
    it :: Bool (bound at <interactive>:31:1)
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern matching is possible:

1. for the arguments of a function equation
2. in the `pat <- expr` constructs in guards, do-expressions and list comprehensions
3. in value bindings left from the equal sign in let/where
4. for the arguments of a lambda expression
5. in case alternatives

You can't use a pattern in an expression except in the aforementioned places.

What you want is to check if there is a tuple whose left element is 'A'. You can say

```
'A' `elem` (map fst [ ('A', 'B') ] )
```

Or you can use `elemBy` from `Data.List` thus:

```
elemBy (\x y -> x == fst y) 'A'  [ ('A', 'B') ]
```